# Unit test failing on Angular service with promises

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, nools

JSFiddle showing the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/ggvfwoeL/3/

I have an Angular application that involves a service for generating threats. The threat generation is done using the [nools](https://github.com/C2FO/nools) rule engine. The service exposes a function `generateForElement` that returns a promise. The function looks like this (see the JSFiddle for full details):

```
var Element = function (element) { this.type = element.attributes.type; }
var Threats = function () { this.collection = []; }    

    function generateForElement(element) {
           var threats = new Threats();
           var el = new Element(element);
           flow.getSession(threats, el).match();
           return $q.when(threats.collection);
    }
```

The rule engine is set up so that when you call `generateForElement` with an element that is a `tm.Process` type, it generates 2 threats. Here is the code that defines the rules (obviously this is much simplified to make the question clearer):

```
function initialiseFlow() {
        return nools.flow('Element threat generation', function (flow) {

            flow.rule('Spoofing Threat Rule', [
                [Element, 'el', 'el.type == "tm.Process"'],
                [Threats, 'threats']
            ], function (facts) {
                facts.threats.collection.push('Spoofing');
            });

            flow.rule('Tampering Threat Rule', [
                [Element, 'el', 'el.type == "tm.Process"'],
                [Threats, 'threats']
            ], function (facts) {
                facts.threats.collection.push('Tampering');
            });
        });
    }
```

When I manually test this in my application I see the 2 threats being generated. But my unit test is failing on this line

```
expect(threats.length).toEqual(2);
```

With error

```
Error: Expected 1 to equal 2.
```

So it appears that only 1 threat is being generated. The unit test definition is like this:

```
describe('threatengine service', function () {

    var threatengine;
    var $rootScope;

    beforeEach(function () {

        angular.mock.module('app')

        angular.mock.inject(function (_$rootScope_, _threatengine_) {
            threatengine = _threatengine_;
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        });

        $rootScope.$apply();
    });

    describe('threat generation tests', function () {

        it('process should generate two threats', function () {

            var element = { attributes: { type: 'tm.Process' }};
            var threats;
            threatengine.generateForElement(element).then(function (data) {
                threats = data;
            });
            expect(threats).toBeUndefined();
            $rootScope.$apply();
            expect(threats).toBeDefined();
            expect(threats.length).toEqual(2);
        });
    });
});
```

Clearly I am doing something wrong. As I said, when I run the full application I definitely get 2 threats which make me think the fault is either with the unit test, or maybe with how I am handling the promises in my service, but I just can't see it.

**Why is my unit test failing?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem is in `flow.getSession(threats, el).match();` call which is called synchronously in your code, but originally it seems to be asynchronous (I am not familiar with nools, but [here are the docs](https://github.com/C2FO/nools#firing-the-rules)). So even if you place `console.log` inside handlers for both rules, you'll see that rules get processed way more later than your following sync code. The solution for it is to use a promise, which `.match()` returns:

```
function generateForElement(element) {
    var threats = new Threats();
    var el = new Element(element);
    // handle async code via promises and resolve it with custom collection
    return flow.getSession(threats, el).match().then(function () {
      return threats.collection;
    });
}
```

The other issue is in a test file. There, you also have async code, but you process it like sync code. See [Asynchronous Support in Jasmine docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support). Basically, you have to tell Jasmine if your tests are async and notify it when they are done.

```
it('process should generate two threats', function (done) {
    // telling Jasmine that code is async ----------^^^

    var element = { attributes: { type: 'tm.Process' }};

    // this call is async
    threatengine.generateForElement(element).then(function (threats) {
        expect(threats).toBeUndefined();
        expect(threats).toBeDefined();
        expect(threats.length).toEqual(2);

        done(); // telling Jasmine that code has completed
    });

    // is required to start promises cycle if any
    $rootScope.$apply();
});
```

[Here is a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4yhnnjft/6/).

**Update:**

Here is a spec for Jasmine 1.3, it uses [another API](http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) for async flow:

```
it('process should generate two threats', function (done) {

    var element = { attributes: { type: 'tm.Process' }};
    var threats;

    runs(function () {
        threatengine.generateForElement(element).then(function (data) {
            threats = data;
        });
        $rootScope.$apply();
        });

        waitsFor(function () {
            return typeof threats !== 'undefined';
    });

    runs(function () {
        expect(threats).not.toBeUndefined();
        expect(threats).toBeDefined();
        expect(threats.length).toEqual(20);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have a small problem with it though - in your fiddle, if you change the expected length of the threats collection, say from 2 to 20, the test still passes!? See this: http://jsfiddle.net/cjbmy5mn/1/

Comment: Oh, I guess I know what's the reason. I've just noticed that you use Jasmine 1.3, but I've posted my solution for Jasmine 2.x. It is funny that tests were passing though. [Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjbmy5mn/3/) for Jasimine 1.3, it has different API for working with async code ([see the docs](http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support)).

Comment: I am not sure about nools though, because you said it works for you when doing manual tests, so I'd investigate if it really works ok on a live site with synchronous flow.

Comment: In fact I made a mistake - I am using Jasmine 2.x - I adapted an existing fiddle and forgot to check the versions :oS And when I changed the versions on your fiddle it doesn't produce any output :o( Would you be able to do a new one based with Jasmine 2.x - sorry for being a pain, and thanks very much for your help

Comment: I got it working on JSBin - [link](http://jsbin.com/nenelotonu/edit?html,js,output), on JSFiddle I get an empty screen too. Not sure why it fails in there.

Comment: Thanks! Finally I got it working on JSFiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/4yhnnjft/6/. I updated your answer with this link and will now mark is as correct.